# Check if values of objects are the same

Tags: javascript, json, loops, object

I am trying to check if object values are the same and if so return true.
For example, if all Fridays are 'ok' return true. If not return false.

```
{
"paul":{"Friday":"ok","Saturday":"OK","Sunday":"--"},
"peter":{"Friday":"ok","Saturday":"--","Sunday":"ok"},
"mary":{"Friday":"ok","Saturday":"OK","Sunday":"--"}
}
```

I tried solving it with a counter and it works but it seems robust. Are there any better solutions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`Array#every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) method to check all elements in an array that satisfies certain conditions.

```js
const obj = {
  "paul": {
    "Friday": "ok",
    "Saturday": "OK",
    "Sunday": "--"
  },
  "peter": {
    "Friday": "ok",
    "Saturday": "--",
    "Sunday": "ok"
  },
  "mary": {
    "Friday": "ok",
    "Saturday": "OK",
    "Sunday": "--"
  }
};

console.log(
  Object.values(obj).every(o => o.Friday === 'ok')
)
```